# Using masonry + infinite scroll in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I know many questions has been asked on jquery masonry + infinite scroll, but i've read and tried everything but still it doesnt work on me. I wonder if anyone could help me out with this.

I'm creating a website with wordpress.
My page shows all the post under certain category in masonry style (image loading).
I wanna make the contents to be loaded automatically when scroll.

This's my code.

(1) Wordpress template

```
<?php
 $args = array(
'post_type'     => 'custom_post',
'posts_per_page' => '10',
'category__in' => "$cat_id",
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'orderby'       => 'date',
'order'         => 'ASC'
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<div id="masonryArea" class="clearfix">
<?php while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); ?>
<div class="entry">
  /* displaying the image here */
</div>
</div>
<nav id="page-nav">
    <a href="#"></a>
</nav>
```

(2) jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // masonry 
    var $container = jQuery('#masonryArea');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry({ 
        itemSelector: '.entry',
        columnWidth: 250
    });
});
$container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector : '#page-nav',
    nextSelector : '#page-nav a',
    itemSelector: '.entry',
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'End of entry',
        img: 'http://phototravel.flop.jp/wp-content/themes/pt/images/loading.gif'
    }
},
function(newElements){
    // hide new items while they are loading
    var $newElems = $(newElements).css({opacity:0});
    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        newElems.animate({opacity:1});
        $container.masonry('appended', $newElems, true);
    });
}
);
});
```

I dont know where i went wrong, but the contents just wont reload..

Anyone could point me out?

Thank you.

Updated:
I just know there's option for debug, and when i turn it on, it gives me

> Sorry, we couldn't parse your Next (Previous Posts) URL. Verify your the css selector points >to the correct A tag. If you still get this error: yell, scream, and kindly ask for help at >infinite-scroll.com.

I guess there must be something wrong with:

```
<nav id="page-nav">
<a href="#"></a>
</nav>
```

And i finally realized that the href must be something valid.

Now the problem is, my page shows all the posts from one category in Wordpress.
What's the link(href) for the remaining 10 posts from the same category?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some actual navigational links, put the following in the `functions.php` file of you WP theme:

```
function so16718316_content_nav( $loop ) {
    if ( $loop->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
        <nav id="page-nav" class="navigation" role="navigation">
            <?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'my_textdomain' ) ); ?>
            <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'my_textdomain' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #page-nav .navigation -->
    <?php endif;
}
```

and call the function in you template file:

```
<?php so16718316_content_nav( $loop ); ?>
```

Comment: diggy, i've replied you in another comment. could you please help me check it out? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks diggy, you pointed me to the correct way! But there is still some issue with it.
Sorry i cant use the "reply" function because my message was too long..

It doesnt work with me the following.

```
<?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'my_textdomain' ) ); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'my_textdomain' ) ); ?
```

I guess it was because i was using custom post type UI , so when i googled and changed it to the following it works.

```
<?php previous_posts_link('≪ Previous', $loop->max_num_pages); ?>
<?php next_posts_link('More ≫', $loop->max_num_pages); ?>
```

But one thing is, the URL are ***/page/2 which is not found in my side.

My page was actually fetching all the custom posts entry in a category, so i don't have any pages with /page/2.
The sample is here.
http://phototravel.flop.jp/category/japan/showa/

Is that infinite scroll doesnt work with custom post type?
Or i'm still lacking of something?

I guess i'm a bit nearer to the solution now...

Comment: I'Ve changed the link to
    
    <a href="/category/category_name?page=<?php echo $paged; ?>"></a>

and it should be ok, but the $paged isnt increasing which makes it loading the same contents